# Can I configure firefox to show all tabs?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

On firefox 23.0.1, there are arrows left and right of the tabs bar, as firefox hides some tabs if you have "too many" opened.

I really dislike this behavior, as sometimes tabs opened recently, at the right end, will be literally hidden from view, requiring one more click to show it.

I've found some discutions online about tab behavior, even a setting to change in about:config, but nothing works at the moment.

[image: annoying arrow for tabs in firefox 23]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the addon [Prevent Tab Overflow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noverflow/):

> This simple yet powerful addon allows your tabs to shrink to a smaller
>   size before going into overflow.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to some extent without using an extension by following these instructions: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1253108 .  It is limited to a minimum of 50px.

```
(1) In a new tab, type or paste about:config in the address bar and
    press Enter/Return.
    Click the button promising to be careful or accepting the risk.

(2) In the search box above the list, type or paste tabm and pause while
    the list is filtered

(3) Double-click the browser.tabs.tabMinWidth preference to display a
    dialog where you can edit the default value of 76 to your
    preferred value (no lower than 50, no higher than 225), then
    click OK
```

I could not find the extensions mentioned in the previous two answers.

Comment: This answer works and should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

Extension from magicandre1981's answer lets you to set minimum width only to 40,  [Custom Tab Width](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/custom-tab-width/) lets you to set minimum width to 20